# how to add stopword handler in weka using java

Tags: java, weka, stop-words

I have a filter and a classifier which are executed with:

```
filter.setStopwordsHandler(new MyStopWordsHandler(stopwords_filename));
```

The code of `MyStopWordsHandler` is:

```
public class MyStopWordsHandler implements StopwordsHandler{

    BufferedReader bufferedReader ;
    HashSet<String> myStopWords;
    String text;
    public MyStopWordsHandler(String filename) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        myStopWords = new HashSet<String>();
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            String line;
            text = "";
            while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                myStopWords.add(line);
            }
            reader.close();
            System.out.println(myStopWords.size());
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //myStopWords.add("the");
        //myStopWords.add("there");
    }

    public boolean isStopword(String word) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return myStopWords.contains(word);
    }

}
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Arunim, please tell us what did you expect and how was the experienced behavior different from your expectations. "its not working" does not specify the problem.

Comment: well,when i write filter.setStopwordsHandler(new MyStopWordsHandler(stopwords_filename)); inside try and catch ,an exception is thrown.Code is shown below-:

Comment: try{  filter.setStopwordsHandler(new MyStopWordsHandler(stopwords_filename));} catch (Exception e) {
   
          e.printStackTrace();
   }

Comment: the problem is no exception is shown

Comment: but if I explicitly write System.out.println("Problem found when evaluating"); ,this message is displayed

Comment: Now ,I realize the problem is in Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(trainData);
   eval.crossValidateModel(classifier, trainData, 4, new Random(1),new Object[] { });

Comment: the exception thrown is

Comment: java.io.NotSerializableException:

Comment: Then the problem is that your object is not serializable. The solution might be to use an object of a class which implements the Serializable interface, possibly inherited from the class you instantiated your object from.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an additional consideration: If you can summarize your Stopwords in a regular expression, you can extend the StopwordsHandler in the following way. This will come in handy if you cannot write down all the stopwords, but rather want to provide a pattern:

```
import weka.core.stopwords.StopwordsHandler;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegExStopwords implements StopwordsHandler {

    private final Pattern pattern;

    public RegExStopwords(String regexString) {
        pattern = Pattern.compile(regexString);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isStopword(String s) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        return matcher.find();
    }
}
```

and add it to your filter

```
filter.setStopwordsHandler(new RegExStopwords("([0-9]|@|n\\/a|[\\%\\€\\$\\£])"));
```

You can find a small tutorial here: http://www.giombetti.com/2016/03/06/using-a-regular-expression-to-specify-stop-words-in-weka-machine-learning-from-java/